# regexpression [R] "About 52,883,038 results"

Tags: numbers, grep, expression, sequence

I want to parse an html webpage (Specifically a Google Search Results Page)
Looking for the specific counter string

> "About *many results"

where `*many` can range from 0 to 999,999,999,999 results

> grep("About [0-9] results",file)

I can't figure out how to incorporate the range of numbers (including commas) into the regular expression. Can anyone clarify? I've looked for similar questions posted, but their codes do not work for this task.

I'm guessing introduce some kind of wildcard "." but I don't think I'm using it correctly
The structure I had in mind was

> Any#Times { { Any#Times( [0-9] ) },}

**Solved own question...** 
didn't have to be fancy at all

> "About .* results"

works fine

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the content of the page then your .* works, but could get a very long and incorrect string.

If you want to make sure that you get only numbers, try:

```
"About ([0-9]+|[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*) results"
```

I've tested it with `grep -E` and it'll give you ungrouped numbers:

```
About 10000000 results
```

as well as grouped numbers using British/English conventions:

```
About 100,000 results
```

but not non-numbers:

```
About a bajillion results
```

or badly grouped numbers:

```
About 100,0 results
```